# Let's Encrpyt and JupyterHub

Tags: jupyter, lets-encrypt

I will use Let’s Encrypt and JupyterHub. I got domain-key.txt, domain-crt.txt, domain-csr.txt and account-key.txt.

The created files from Let’s Encrypt uses base64, which is readable in ASCII, not binary format: The certificates is allredy in PEM format. Just change the extension to *.pem.

For JupyterHub I need a privkey.pem and fullchain.pem. I copied domain-key.txt to privkey.pem and doamin-crt.txt to fullchain.pem.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

domain-key.txt is privkey.pem and domain-crt.txt is fullchain.pem because the last one includes your cert and the Let’s Encrypt Intermediate cert.